.html Requests never reach the app.routes.ts in Angular 17+
In Angular the official example with the urlmatcher for matching .html files does not work.
when a request comes in, the angular app responds with Cannot GET /test.html
when debugging the app.routes.ts, the code never reaches the matcher function
the code sample in angular.io is:
export function htmlFiles(url: UrlSegment[]) {
  return url.length === 1 && url[0].path.endsWith('.html') ? ({consumed: url}) : null;
}
export const routes = [{ matcher: htmlFiles, component: AnyComponent }];

tested in Angular 17+

i tried the sample code on angular.io version 17+
